# how to get single row in select count(*) in following query postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select count(*) from ordrer 
inner join ordrelinjer on ordrelinjer.ordrenr = ordrer.ordrenr 
group by ordrelinjer.varetekst
```

This query return 4 rows, but I want to return 4 in `count(*)`, how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem that you're looking for the distinct number of values for ordrelinjer.varetekst, which would be:

```
select count(distinct ordrelinjer.varetekst)
from   ordrer 
join   ordrelinjer on ordrelinjer.ordrenr = ordrer.ordrenr;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting 4 row because of group by. If you need distinct group count, you can try subquery.

```
select count(*) 
from (
   select count(*) 
   from ordrer 
      inner join ordrelinjer on ordrelinjer.ordrenr=ordrer.ordrenr 
   group by ordrelinjer.varetekst
) t
```

Comment: is there any other way without subquery, because subquery take long time to execute

Answer (score 1):

invoke without group by

```
select count(*) from ordrer inner join ordrelinjer on ordrelinjer.ordrenr=ordrer.ordrenr
```